# Problems with permissions in GCLOUD

Tags: dialogflow-es, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I have created an Organization and a Folder with the company's development email account.

The idea is to have sufficient permissions so that by API you can create projects, link these to dialogflow.

I would also use an API to create several DialogFLow projects without creating it on the Google console side

Comment: what issues you are facing?

Comment: When a use the Dialogflow API to create Agent i only can create a agent by project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create projects via API in GCP you need to have [Project Creator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles) role (`resourcemanager.projectCreator`) at the Organization level. You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/default-access-control) on how to grant this permission.

Then you can create agents in Dialogflow using [`projects.agent`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/agent) API method. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/access-control#roles) documentation You will learn aboutthe necessary Dialogflow permissions.